# Can I make .pro file using .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

Can I make project file `.pro` using `.cpp` and `.h` files,This [GitHub demo](https://github.com/cesarbs/sizegripitem) file contain `CMakeLists.txt,MainWindow.cpp MainWindow.h,MainWindow.uimain.cpp` files,but there is no `.pro` file how can I make `.pro`

Comment: There is a CMakeLists.txt so you probably don't need a pro file.

Comment: @drescherjm then how can I open project through QT

Comment: I believe QtCreator will use the CMakeLists.txt. I do pretty much all of my Qt development without using .pro files at all. Although with that said I don't use qtcreator much, I mainly use CMake to generate Visual Studio projects..

Comment: @drescherjm ya,your correct :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute this code the first step is to generate the .pro for it opens a terminal and executes:

```
qmake -project
```

A .pro file is generated with the name of the folder containing it and will contain content similar to:

**sizegripitem-master.pro**

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.1) Tue Oct 24 12:36:31 2017
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = sizegripitem-master
INCLUDEPATH += .

# The following define makes your compiler warn you if you use any
# feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Input
HEADERS += SizeGripItem.h demo/MainWindow.h
FORMS += demo/MainWindow.ui
SOURCES += SizeGripItem.cpp demo/main.cpp demo/MainWindow.cpp
```

After these we have to indicate the modules, as I see the classes only need the modules core, gui and widget for this we add the following:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Another thing you should do is update a line of code to be compatible with Qt5, in the file main.cpp changes:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

to:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

Comment: open a terminal, if you are in windows a cmd in the same folder of the code.

Comment: @Rooter If you are in windows a simple way to open the cmd is to press Ctrl + Shitf and then right click, in one of the options will open the cmd.

Comment: @Rooter Another much simpler option is to copy the code that I have placed in my answer.

Comment: Can you send the complete project file to me smwhack10@gmail.com

Comment: @Rooter I uploaded the corrected project in the following link: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46916327/sizegripitem-master , Do not forget to mark my answer as correct if I help you

Comment: Thank you very much,unfortunately my Qt creator is not working just now,this error will pop up, https://i.imgur.com/zeBsFEj.png

Comment: I find that error very strange. I am running correctly, have you opened another project and generated the same error?

Comment: No this isn't your project file issue, My QT creator problem,these type of errors occurring most of the times.

Comment: I find it strange, maybe your antivirus is generating these problems.